# Cast to generic type in Swift 5

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

I'd like to write a generic function, that fetches some kind of data locally, using the Core Data framework. I wrote the function like this:

```
func fetch<T:NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type = T.self, completion: @escaping (([T]?) -> ())) {
    do {
        let data = try context.fetch(T.fetchRequest()) as [T]
        completion(data)
    } catch {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

However, the complier tells me this error "Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to type '[T]' in coercion, arguments to generic parameter 'Element' ('Any' and 'T') are expected to be equal"

Is there the possibility to do this kind of cast?

Comment: Do you realise `fetch` returns an array of `T`, not just one `T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
func fetch<T:NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type = T.self, completion: @escaping (([T]?) -> ())) {
    do {
        let data = try context.fetch(T.fetchRequest()) as? [T]
        completion(data)
    } catch {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

(As Sweeper has pointed out `fetch` returns an array, so you have to cast the result to `[T]` and not just `T`)

Comment: Do you write ```as?``` (my answer) or ```as``` (your edited question)?

Comment: Happy to help :-)